# Cheapest transport from Akasaka to Narita Airport (2 pax)

Tags: budget, tokyo, nrt

What's the cheapest method for 2 people to get to NRT from Akasaka (and approximate time). We'll be making the journey next Sunday in the morning and have found multiple routes online, but maybe there are cheaper alternatives if there are two of us (buses/ limos etc). Please let me know your thoughts. We have an IC card each as well if that makes it cheaper than plain tickets.

Comment: @willeke: It's a journey of only 66 km and the fares seem to be about 3000 yen per person or less. You can estimate for yourself the commission that a professional travel agent would earn on that. It seems unlikely to me that a travel agent would find it worth their time to assist the OP with this.

Answer (score 3):

The cheapest option will almost certainly be taking the Marunouchi Line subway from Akasaka-Mitsuke to Ginza (Y170) and transferring to the [Access Narita](http://accessnarita.jp/en/home/) bus to Narita (Y1000).  Or you can also take the subway an extra stop to Tokyo stn, which is also served by Access Narita and has twice as many departures.

Note that IC cards are *not* valid for the bus, you'll need to pay cash as you board or buy online in advance by credit card.

Comment: to clarify, those look like per pax prices

Answer (score 3):

The [Keisei Limited Express](http://www.keisei.co.jp/keisei/tetudou/skyliner/us/nrt_access/tokkyu.html) departs Ueno and Nippori and costs 1030 Yen with an IC card.  This journey will take about 70min.

You can get to Ueno from Akasaka on the Ginza line in about 25min for 200 Yen.

This is a good, cheap and fast option if you want to avoid buses.

Comment: +1, but small nit: the Ginza line doesn't serve Akasaka station.  It does serve both Akasaka-Mitsuke and Tameike-Sanno though, which are nearby.

Answer (score 2):

With an IC card you can go from Akasaka to Machiya on the Chiyoda subway line (195 yen), and from Machiya to the airport via Keisei (973 yen).  This is three yen more expensive than @jpatokal's answer, and slightly more inconvenient as there are two train transfers, instead of relaxing on the bus.  But, this weekend may see some highway congestion due to the 5-day weekend, so you may alleviate some anxiety by taking the train and bypassing the potential traffic jams.

Comment: Machiya is only served by Keisei local trains, so you may be in for a bit of a wait and will likely need to transfer again at Aoto onto a faster limited express (no surcharge).

Comment: Playing around with Jorudan, it looks like you can also catch transfers from the local to the express at Takasago or Yahata, depending on the exact departure time.  On Sunday morning, the total time is ranging between 1:45 and 2:00 -- which, in ideal conditions is slower than the subway + bus.  But, frankly, Tokyo traffic (especially between the inner loops and Urayasu / Disney, which is the route the airport busses also take) scares me during holidays.

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried. Sunday morning will be very quiet, and the holiday impact should be minimal: Narita is not a top destination, the expressway there is not en route to anywhere else, and you'll already be a few days into Silver Week. Even on weekday rush hour it's usually smooth sailing once you get out of central Tokyo.

Comment: Thanks for all comments and answers, will go through in detail ASAP. And my girlfriend is working on Saturday apparently, so Sunday seems to be our first day of Silver week =\ , but a 3-4 day holiday isn't too bad!